# Groups of exponent 4

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a classification of finite nonabelian 2-groups of exponent 4?

What about, finite nonabelian 3-groups of exponent 3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no classification of finite groups of exponent 4. You might find [this paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jsallb6xi0rru8n/Mann%20On%20the%20orders%20of%20groups%20of%20exponent%20four.pdf?dl=0) interesting - it contains lots of information about how the group Burnside group $B(m,4)$ grows (all $m$-generator exponent-4 groups are quotients of this group).

There is also no classification of finite groups of exponent 3. However it is known that these groups must be $2$-Engel and class three. Furthermore in this case the precise size of the corresponding Burnside group is known: $B(m,3)$ is a finite group of size $3^{m + \binom{m}{2} + \binom{m}{3}}$.

Comment: Please activate the link of "this paper". Many thanks.

Comment: Access was denied on the link: was it a paper of M. Vaughn-Lee, who has worked a lot on such groups?

Comment: @user100452, Dropbox seems to have changed its policy on link sharing, and I can't figure out how to make the paper public. Please email me -- my details are on my user page -- and I'll happily send you a copy of the paper.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, It's a paper by Avinoam Mann: *On the orders of groups of exponent 4*.

Comment: @NickGill : Thanks.. Vaughn-Lee has done a lot of work on groups of exponent $4$.

Answer (score 9):

> What about, finite nonabelian 3-groups
>   of exponent 3?

Those are all quotients of the Burnside group $B(m,3)$ for some value for $m$.

Comment: Tom, you beat me by 1 minute!!

Comment: But your answer is more complete than mine :)